# Unable to add multiple html classes with a VAR string in MVC 3

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm having this strange issue with MVC 3 in that I cannot use a variable to assign multiple classes to an html string.  It seems to break every time I use a space in the string.  For instance, if I use this variable:

```
var MultipleClasses = "ClassOne ClassTwo";
```

and then assign that to an html element as a class:

```
<tr class = @MultipleClasses>blah blah</tr>
```

The second class always displays outside of the quotes:

```
<tr class = "ClassOne" ClassTwo>blah blah</tr>
```

Any ideas?  Or, any suggestions for a work around?  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<tr class = "@MultipleClasses">blah blah</tr>
```

It's because you have no quotes around the attribute value, then you're doing a space, so it thinks you're trying to start the next attribute on the html element

Comment: @StuartBranham I think it lost it's way :(. HTML5 is a step in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

In my example I had an action link and I applied multiple classes to it for example, see blow:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Administration", "Index", "Admin", null, new { @class = "btn btn_c" }) 


My css is as follows:

.btn
{
    color: yellow;
}

.btn_c
{
    background-color: red;
}
```